# @DataJpaTest ignores `spring.datasource.url` configuration. How to fix?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I had issues with `@DataJpaTest`, because tables fail to be created, due to missing schema [1]. So I thought, I could cheat spring by creating schema in connection string as in:

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:SCH;MODE=Oracle;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=create schema if not exists SCH
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
```

however mysteriously, that did not help. Why?

quick peek at excerpt from test log:

```
2019-02-13 17:48:12.735  INFO [CCH,,,] 28586 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:11247702-6bc4-44b9-be65-9639ebb8d695;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
```

**well it's because @DataJpaTest ignores datasource configured in application.properties and rather uses autoconfigured h2 database**

I found that I can use `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)` but that does not work either and fails with `Unknown host specified`. What host???

So any ideas how to confince @DataJpaTest to use configured data source?

[1] [Using @DataJpaTest I cannot force h2 to create schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54655013/using-datajpatest-i-cannot-force-h2-to-create-schema?noredirect=1#comment96110295_54655013)

Comment: Do you have Oracle jars in your pom dependencies? If not, they won't be configured as data-source is not on the classpath.

Comment: MODE=Oracle actually works even if oracle driver is not on class path, but thanks for hint. I retest everything, and actually found out, that it was my bad. Given `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)` actually turns off autoconfigured embedded h2 database and uses the one declared in project configuration. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: For me it was a dependency error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677084

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I apologize, it was my mistake in project/tests configuration.

To give some answer: By default `@DataJpaTest` uses embeded h2 databaze and ignores the connection string declared in application.properties. Annotation `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)` disables this behavior, and db configured in application.properties will be used by `@DataJpaTest` test.