# Problem running unit test under DataJPATest

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-data, h2

This is my first attempt to write a Spring boot unit test using the H2 in-memory database.  The guides I have found make it look simple, but I can't get it to work.

H2 is generating a long sequence of syntax errors, I believe in trying to execute all the DDL necessary for the entities.

My unit test class:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @DataJpaTest()
    public class AppRepositoryTest
    {

        @Autowired
        private TestEntityManager entityManager;

        @Autowired
        private OrganizationRepository organizationRepository;

        @Test
        public void test_findAppsForUserAndTeam()
        {
            // given
            Organization organization = new Organization();
            organization.setOrganizationCode("o");
            organization.setOrganizationName("O");
            entityManager.persist(organization);
            entityManager.flush();

            // when
            Organization found = organizationRepository.getOrganizationWithParents("o")
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Org not found"));

            // then
            assertThat(found.getOrganizationName(), is("O"));
        }
    }
```

The first thing I had to do was create the schema, which I did by adding this line into resources/schema.sql:

```
CREATE SCHEMA  IF NOT EXISTS EUAMDB;
```

Running the test results in a failure, and a long string of syntax errors, like:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "drop table euamdb.public.access_requests if exists" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
        ...
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "DROP TABLE EUAMDB.PUBLIC.[*]ACCESS_REQUESTS IF EXISTS"; SQL statement:
drop table euamdb.public.access_requests if exists [42000-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
```

Appreciate any help.

Update:

I understand that I need to make Spring use euamdb as the database name (thanks to @Evgenij).  Currently it generates a random database name, as I see in the log like:

```
Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:9929f516-5795-477c-8a8a-343b4b30ebf9;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
```

If I stop the code in the debugger before it creates the datasource, and replace the random db name with "euamdb", then the test runs.  I just can't figure out how to tell spring what to use as the H2 database name.

I have tried to change the @DataJpaTest annotation to set the property as:

```
@DataJpaTest(properties = {"spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:euamdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false"})
```

and also tried adding this annotation:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:euamdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false"})
```

and finally changed the spring.datasource.url in the application.yml, but none of these things has changed the way the execution sets the database name.

Comment: I think the solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54675623/datajpatest-ignores-spring-datasource-url-configuration-how-to-fix

Answer (score 0):

In commands like `DROP TABLE EUAMDB.PUBLIC.ACCESS_REQUESTS` the `EUAMDB` part is the name of the catalog (in H2 it is the name of the database), the `PUBLIC` part is the name of the schema (`PUBLIC` is a default schema in H2 and not only in H2), and `ACCESS_REQUESTS` is the name of the table. So you don't need the `EUAMDB` schema, but you need to rename your database to `EUAMDB` instead. For example, such name will be used with `jdbc:h2:mem:euamdb` or `jdbc:h2:./euamdb` URLs.

Comment: Thanks - how do I set it up so that the unit test will use the H2 database name euamdb when running the unit test?

Comment: You should have JDBC URL somewhere (for example, your libraries can use `spring.datasource.url` parameter in the file `application.properties`). You need to use `euamdb` as the database name in that URL. Another solution is to use the `IGNORE_CATALOGS=TRUE` parameter in the URL or you can execute `SET IGNORE_CATALOGS TRUE;` command somewhere during initialization of your application: https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#set_ignore_catalogs

Comment: I have another (non-in-memory, postgresql) database set up in application.yml, but my understanding is that the DataJpaTest annotation replaces that with H2 for the purposes of running the test.  So will it even matter what I put into application.properties for the H2 JDBC URL, and will that break my runtime database?  I would have thought there was some way in the annotation to do this.

Comment: How your project is organized? It can have `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources` directories with different configuration files or something like it.

Comment: See my updated post... I just can't figure out how to tell Spring to use the database name euamdb - it always uses a randomly generated db name

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this, though this solution does not really answer the question directly.

I determined there was no need for the catalog = "euamdb" portion of the @Table annotation on entities.  So when those were removed across all entities, the test is able to run.  I don't see any impact to the application either.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still struggling with @DataJpaTest for more flexible customization:

```
    @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
    @DataJpaTest
    @AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
    @TestPropertySource(properties = {
           "spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver",
           "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:api_auth_test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MySQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE",
           "spring.datasource.username=sa",
           "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop",
           "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop",
           "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true"
    })
    class MyRepositoryTest {
        ...
    }
```

That is, use @AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = NONE) to disable default h2 substitution, use @TestPropertySource.properties to override the properties defined in application.properties.

Note: "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true" overcomes any reserved word of the database.